# MonacaでjQuery mobileがうまくロードできない件について

Tags: monaca, jquery-mobile

現状Monacaにて、"CSS/JSコンポーネントの追加と削除"の項目でjQuery mobile(1.2)を追加したのですが、それに応じてloader.cssが変更されていないようで、自分でcomponentsのjquery mobileディレクトリにあるcssファイルにリンクをはらないとcssが適応されておりません。

Monacaのドキュメントを見る限りは、loader.cssを読み込めばコンポーネントで追加したCSS関係のファイルは読み込まれると思っていたのですが、こちらは自分でcssへのリンクをはる必要があるのでしょうか。

お教えいただけると幸いです。